# MathNet Numerics - Fourier - "Specified method not supported"

Tags: exception, fft, managed, mathnet-numerics, numerics

I have a C# application, I installed MathNet.Numerics 3.17.0 via Nuget.

I am trying to use the fourier functions. When I run this line of code:

```
Fourier.Forward2D(n);
```

It throws an exception "Specified method not supported".

```
Console.WriteLine(MathNet.Numerics.Control.LinearAlgebraProvider.ToString());
```

Returns "Managed".

I swear this was working, but now it is broken.

Any ideas on how to make this work?

FYI I was using the MKL package for a minute, that seems to work. I want to use the native package "Managed" because I am distributing the application via clickonce....

Any ideas appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the 2D and multi-dimensional FFT support has indeed been added in v3.15 with support for the MKL provider only, but not the managed provider. See [release notes](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/ReleaseNotes.html#3-15-0-2016-12-27). This is exceptional, since it is a fundamental goal of Math.NET Numerics that the managed provider shall be feature complete. We definitely want to fill this gap, but unfortunately I cannot give any time estimates on when we will be there.

Answer (score 0):

Since the managed support for Fourier2D is still lacking, here is how to use the native package in case it is viable:

```cs
MathNet.Numerics.Control.UseNativeMKL();
```

It is also necessary to import the "MathNet.Numerics.MKL.Win" (or another for your platform) package to add Intel MKL support to MathNet.